# Minify maven plugin,does not add minified file to maven local repository

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, minify

I'm using minify maven plugin with following configuration in POM -

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
             <configuration>
                 <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>${JAVA_HOME_1_7}/bin/javac</executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
         <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>crf</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                      <jsSourceDir>crf/js</jsSourceDir>
                      <jsSourceIncludes>
                            <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                        </jsSourceIncludes>
                        <jsTargetDir>crf/js</jsTargetDir>
                       <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                        <closureCreateSourceMap>false</closureCreateSourceMap>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                 <execution>
                    <id>bundle-configuration-minify</id>
                    <configuration>
                      <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                      <closureCreateSourceMap>false</closureCreateSourceMap>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When i build the component(Say 'component-war' using *mvn clean install*), i see the target(component-war) has a minified JavaScript.But Maven local repo does not contain the minified file.
Due to which when i package the project(Say 'project-ear') target does not contain the minified file.

I Also have the following configuration in my POM -

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/urlrewritefilter-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/io-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xtags-*.jar,**/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.pdf,**/*.txt,**/*px,**/*dummyfile,**/*.properties,**/*.class,**/*.png,**/*.css,**/*.js,**/*.jsp,**/*.jspf,**/*.xsl,**/*.html,**/*.htm,**/*.vm,**/*.tld,**/*.gif,**/readme,**/*.zip,**/*.jpg,**/*.zul,**/*.zs,**/*.eot,**/*.svg,**/*.ttf,**/*.woff,**/*.swf
                </packagingIncludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: War file does not contains minified file.

Comment: Do you mean your WAR file in target folder contains minified file and the same file installed in local repo does NOT CONTAIN it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. WAR file does not contain minified file.

Comment: So it's easy: you don't have minified file within local repository because you don't have it within target WAR file. You must track where minified file is written and how WAR file is assembled. Finally, you must configure one of them: minified file should be written to folder which is included in WAR assembly or WAR assembly must include folder where minified file is written

Comment: Yes, i do have a folder. And folder contains the minified files.But WAR does not have minified file. i think WAR is reading from Source.

Comment: Also in my terminal, i am able to see a status saying files are being compressed

Comment: Could you present path to some of minified file (against project root)? I guess is should be like target/component-war/crf/js/abc.js

Comment: i have specified path crf/js so i m able to get minified files under crf/js.But the problem is there are no minified files in WAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must delete:

<execution>
<id>crf</id>
<del><phase>package</phase></del>

because for WAR project in phase **package**  maven-war-plugin has priority over other plugins (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins) - WAR is build before minification.

*BTW, it explains why Maven has phase prepare-package and do not have post-package; everything defined in package is effectively post-package*

That's not enough, because maven-war-plugin will overwrite minified files. You must configure it to ignore original JS files, because their minified versions are already prepared by minify plugin ([Exclude source files from WAR package](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/examples/exclude.html))

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
   <configuration>
       <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/urlrewritefilter-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/io-*.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xtags-*.jar,**/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.pdf,**/*.txt,**/*px,**/*dummyfile,**/*.properties,**/*.class,**/*.png,**/*.css,**/*.js,**/*.jsp,**/*.jspf,**/*.xsl,**/*.html,**/*.htm,**/*.vm,**/*.tld,**/*.gif,**/readme,**/*.zip,**/*.jpg,**/*.zul,**/*.zs,**/*.eot,**/*.svg,**/*.ttf,**/*.woff,**/*.swf
      </packagingIncludes>

<!--HERE **************** -->
      <warSourceExcludes>crf/js/*.js</warSourceExcludes>
<!--HERE **************** -->

     <archive>
         <manifest>
             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
             <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
         </manifest>
       </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*BTW, your maven war plugin configuration (packagingIncludes) suggests you have a mess in project. You should consider clean it up, because my proposal extends configuration and any further unnecessary extension cause whole configuration hard to understood*

Comment: Thanks,that resolved the issue for me. To reiterate what changes i have made:   <warSourceExcludes>**/*.js</warSourceExcludes> in maven-war-plugin and have changed jsEngine to 'yuicompressor-maven-plugin' and <phase>prepare-package</phase>